# String formatting on concatenated strings?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I run into this situation:

```
msg = 'stackoverflow is {subject}'+ ' for me'.format(subject='useful')

msg = 'stackoverflow is {subject}'.format(subject='useful') + ' for me'
```

First one prints:

> stackoverflow is {subject} for me

Second one prints:

> stackoverflow is useful for me

Does not concatenating two strings make a new string that should be treated as a normal string for string formatting input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you would need to use parenthesis in the first solution:

```
msg = ('stackoverflow is {subject}' + ' for me').format(subject='useful')
```

Otherwise, the `.format` call will only apply to the `' for me'` string, which is effectively a no-op:

```
>>> ' for me'.format(subject='useful')
' for me'
>>>
```

With the parenthesis however, the `'stackoverflow is {subject}'` and `' for me'` string literals will first be combined:

```
>>> ('stackoverflow is {subject}' + ' for me')
'stackoverflow is {subject} for me'
>>>
```

and then `.format` will be called on the resulting string.

---

Also, just for the record, you do not need to use `+` in this case since adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated in Python:

```
>>> 'a''b'
'ab'
>>> 'a'      'b'
'ab'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, yea because '.' is being evaluated earlier than plus!

Answer (score 0):

In the above example you're calling `.format()` on the last string, `for me` and therefore not the formatting doesn't work as you expected it to.

Wrap your string concat in parenthesis and call format on the resulting string and the formatting will work.